# Excel VBA to dojo - changing a drop down box

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, dojo, internet-explorer-11

I am new here and I am trying to write a VBA Excel script to automate form input for an external website. The website uses dojo and I am using IE11. Is there a way for me to integrate excel vba to dojo?

I am having a lot of trouble changing the drop down box for states to my desired states using the selectedIndex property of the select element. I also tried execScript to try to use Javascript to call dojo functions. I am able to change the input fields (typing fields). I've looked throughout this forum for an answer but nothing has worked. Can anyone help?

Codes I've tried

```
IE.document.currentWindow.execScript code:="dijit.getID('state').set('value','TEXAS');" //returns 80020101 error

IE.document.currentWindow.execScript code:="dojo.eval(dijit.getID('state').set('value','TEXAS'));" //returns 80020101 error

IE.document.getElementById("state").Focus
IE.document.getElementById("state").value = "NEW YORK"
IE.document.getElementById("state").FireEvent ("onchange")

IE.document.getElementById("state").Focus
IE.document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex = 29
IE.document.getElementById("state").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

From the website

```
<div>
<label for="state" id="state_label" class="showHints">State for withholding</label>
<div><select id="state" name="state" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"><option value="ALABAMA">Alabama</option>      <option value="ALASKA">Alaska</option><option value="ARIZONA" selected="selected">Arizona</option><option value="ARKANSAS">Arkansas</option><option value="CALIFORNIA">California</option><option value="COLORADO">Colorado</option><option value="CONNECTICUT">Connecticut</option><option value="DELAWARE">Delaware</option><option value="FLORIDA">Florida</option><option value="GEORGIA">Georgia</option><option value="HAWAII">Hawaii</option><option value="IDAHO">Idaho</option><option value="ILLINOIS">Illinois</option><option value="INDIANA">Indiana</option><option value="IOWA">Iowa</option><option value="KANSAS">Kansas</option><option value="KENTUCKY">Kentucky</option><option value="LOUISIANA">Louisiana</option><option value="MAINE">Maine</option><option value="MARYLAND">Maryland</option><option value="MASSACHUSETTS">Massachusetts</option><option value="MICHIGAN">Michigan</option><option value="MINNESOTA">Minnesota</option><option value="MISSISSIPPI">Mississippi</option><option value="MISSOURI">Missouri</option><option value="MONTANA">Montana</option><option value="NEBRASKA">Nebraska</option><option value="NEVADA">Nevada</option><option value="NEW_HAMPSHIRE">New Hampshire</option><option value="NEW_JERSEY">New Jersey</option><option value="NEW_MEXICO">New Mexico</option><option value="NEW_YORK">New York</option><option value="NORTH_CAROLINA">North Carolina</option><option value="NORTH_DAKOTA">North Dakota</option><option value="OHIO">Ohio</option><option value="OKLAHOMA">Oklahoma</option><option value="ORGEON">Oregon</option><option value="PENNSYLVANIA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RHODE_ISLAND">Rhode Island</option><option value="SOUTH_CAROLINA">South Carolina</option><option value="SOUTH_DAKOTA">South Dakota</option><option value="TENNESSEE">Tennessee</option><option value="TEXAS">Texas</option><option value="UTAH">Utah</option><option value="VERMONT">Vermont</option><option value="VIRGINIA">Virginia</option><option value="WASHINGTON">Washington</option><option value="WEST_VIRGINIA">West Virginia</option><option value="WISCONSIN">Wisconsin</option><option value="WYOMING">Wyoming</option><option value="WASHINGTON_DC">Washington DC</option><option value="PUERTO_RICO">Puerto Rico</option><option value="AMERICAN_SAMOA">American Samoa</option><option value="GUAM">Guam</option><option value="NORTHERN_MARIANA_ISLANDS">N. Mariana Islands</option><option value="US_VIRGIN_ISLANDS">US Virgin Islands</option></select></div>
```

Comment: Is the combo changing value?

Comment: the value changes when i try the .value property. but when i submit the form  value passed through is still the first option which is not correct. when i use the selectedindex property i get "object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Comment: ill take a look, can you supply the url?

Comment: thanks in advance - http://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/salary/

Answer (score 0):

This should help, numeric value for selectedindex.  Sorry, should of spotted that, end of day for me :)

```
Sub x()

Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim s As MSHTML.HTMLSelectElement
Dim e As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set i = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
i.Visible = 1
i.navigate "http://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/salary/"

While i.Busy Or i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set s = i.document.getElementById("state")
s.selectedIndex = 11

While i.Busy Or i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

s.form.submit

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the help but i am still getting the "object doesn't support this property or method" error. i am using IE11, does that affect anything? Also, when i test i.document.getElementById("state").tagName it returns it as "INPUT" and not "SELECT". I am not sure why, but is this why selectedIndex is not working?